# How to get the second digit of a number or string in python?

Tags: python, if-statement, digit

Is there any good idea how to get the second digit of a string?
For example:

```
aaa = 122
bbb = 333

rest = bbb-aaa 
if rest[:2] == 1: 
    do something..
```

Comment: if you could slice an int like that, your slice would give `21`, not `1`.

Comment: Your example is using `int` not `string`.  Do you mean 2nd from the left or right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert the integer to a string first using the built-in `str()` function and then slice it accordingly

So Try this:

```
if str(rest)[1] == '1':
    #do something example:
    print 'hi'
```

Answer (score 3):

Index it:

```
>>> mystr = "123"
>>> mystr[1]
'2'
>>> mystr[-2]
'2'
>>>
```

If it is a number, then you need to convert it to a string first with [`str`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#str):

```
>>> myint = 123
>>> str(myint)[1]
'2'
>>> str(myint)[-2]
'2'
>>>
```

Comment: Another good index would be `-2` as that’s always the second digit from the right; so for a number `1234` it would give you `3`.

Answer (score 0):

def lastsecond(num):

```
if(num>-9 and num<10):
    return -1;
else:
    temp=num/10;
    rem=temp%10;
    return int(rem);
```

number=abs(int(input("enter number : ")))
print("the last second digit of %d is %d"%(number,lastsecond(number)))